# Commerce Minion config patch file

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have created a Custom Minion and added it in Habitat Minion environment json file. I wanted to create a separate patch file for my custom minion.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple.

Put this part of configuration to your Habitat Minion JSON file in Policies values:

```
{
        "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.PolicySetPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
        "PolicySetId": "Entity-PolicySet-{your_policy_name}PolicySet"
      },
```

Create a separate JSON file with your configuration and paste configuration like:

```
{
  "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.PolicySet, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
  "Id": "Entity-PolicySet-{your_policy_name}PolicySet",
  "Version": 1,
  "IsPersisted": false,
  "Name": "{your_policy_name}PolicySet",
  "Policies": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Policy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "Plugin.Habitat.{ProjectName}.Policies.{your_policy_type}, Plugin.Habitat.{ProjectName}",
        "YourPropertyName": "ABC"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After that publish your changes and run Bootstrap()

Comment: When I configure my minion in the environment json, I can use the `RunMinion` API call to invoke the minion, but if I define it in a policy set in a separate file, I get `MinionNotFound`. I have simply copied the minion definition to the policy set so the namespace should be okay. And I have bootstrapped the engine. Any ideas?